# If Else DateTime DayOfWeek C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

For example, a user can view his password if today is Monday or Tuesday and if his schedule is within the time frame (given), compared to the current system time, but even if Today is Monday or Tuesday, if his given time is, let's say 1:30-5:30PM, and it's not yet or it's already past that time, he won't be able to view his password.

I hope you get the drill. The code below works fine, however, if I put the same day twice, like, Tuesday and Tuesday, there happens to be a conflict. How do I fix this conditional statements? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
DateTime systemtime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime timestart = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimestart.Text);
DateTime timeend = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimeend.Text);
var systemday = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
var day1 = Convert.ToString(txtDay1.Text);
var day2 = Convert.ToString(txtDay2.Text);

if (systemday != day1 || systemday != day2)
{
    if (systemtime < timestart || systemtime > timeend)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not authenticated to view your password.", "Get Password Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your password is ...", "Get Password Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    if (systemtime < timestart || systemtime > timeend)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not authenticated to view your password.", "Get Password Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your password is ...", "Get Password Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: For example, the user has Monday and Tuesday (1:30-5:30 PM) as his schedule. An if statement will check if today is Mon or Tues, if it is, another code will check if the time now (3:30PM, for example) is within the user time schedule. Given my example, 3:30PM, he will be able to view his password. But if it is before or after his time, like 12:30PM or 6:30PM, he won't be able to.

Comment: Why are you calling `Convert.ToString` on values which I'd expect to be strings already? (`txtTimestart.Text` and `txtTimeend.Text`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your example, this line of code means: *if  current day(system day) is not monday or not tuesday*.

```
if (systemday != day1 || systemday != day2)
```

Now if today is tuesday then it is not monday which makes first comparison true and it will enter in the if block. if today is monday then it is not tuesday which makes second comparison (Systemday != day2) true. If today is not monday and tuesday then it makes both comparison (systemday != day1 || systemday != day2) true. In short your code will never fall in else.

Now for your problem use

```
if (systemday == day1 || systemday == day2)
{ 
    if(systemtime>=timestart && systemtime <=timeend)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your password is ...", "Get Password Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not authenticated to view your password.", "Get Password Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it. My example is Monday and Friday (1:30-7:30PM). But it says not authenticated. My system time here is 5:25 PM, and it's a Friday. Why's that?

Comment: I edited my code. code block in if else was switched by mistake. Also try to debug the code and see which comparison is wrong according to your problem

Comment: Another example, Monday and Friday (9:30AM-12:45PM). But it enabled the user to get his password. Which is wrong because it's already past 12:45PM here, even though it's a Friday.

Comment: Another problem is how u used your variables. systemday,day1,day2 should be of type DayOfWeek Enum. systemtime, timestart,timeend should be timespan.

Comment: Okay it works fine now. However, if I tried another example, this time it's Tuesday (1:30-7:30PM), the message box doesn't show up. That's why I tried to use an If...Else. Just in case the example has only 1 schedule.

Comment: you r right. and in that case you only need to show messagebox and no need to compare time.

Comment: In which part to I add the code? The message box? before the `if(systemtime>=timestart && systemtime <=timeend)`?

Comment: no. It is else of first if. first if compares that systemday is scheduled day and if it is not scheduled day then execution should go to else.that else should be of first if.